# Trying to Link to App in Header of Facebook Post

Tags: ios, facebook, post

I see that posts from some iOS Apps have their App name and a link back to the App within the title bar of the post. I've been trying to figure out how to set this up to do this. One app, it shows iOS in this space and goes to the Apple page for iOS. On another one of my Apps it shows nothing there. Yet, they both seem to be setup the same way. And I can't figure out how to get the App name and link there instead. Any hints from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is listed in App Center, it should show as attribution in the post.

Do you have the App ID for which one the posts *are* showing the name, and the App ID for which the name *is not* showing in the post?

What method of posting to the users wall do you use? Dialogs, or custom implementations? Can you share your code around that, please?

Comment: Both are listed in the App Center.  I do have the App ID for both.  I am using the standard iOS Facebook popup for both.

Comment: I meant to ask for those ids :) can you post them here?

Comment: 1484953258399620 - Make It 13

Comment: 367587019978121 Add Em Up

Comment: 245631932196183 - Cross Number

Comment: These are showing nothing or showing a generic iOS link.

Comment: Isn't there some step by step guide to make sure you can get this done.  It really shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Do you also have 1) an example post -with- the attribution, and 2) an example post -without- the attribution? You can get the permalinks by hovering over the timestamp of the post. Please make sure they are both public. Thanks!